# merging JAX-RS layer, EJB layer, JSF layer into one POJO in Java EE7?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7

I am going through the tutorial of `Java EE 7` that ships with `GlassFish`.
from my understanding `CDI injection`is possible in `JAX-RS layer` which is not possible in previous
EE versions - correct me if I am wrong.

Further a single bean can be an `EJB`, `WebService` and `managed bean` (for JSF handling).

The example below comes directly from [tutorial](https://github.com/alanbuckeridge/movieplex/blob/master/src/main/java/org/glassfish/movieplex7/rest/MovieFacadeREST.java). As you can see by using three annotations `@Named, @Stateless and @Path`, three layers are combined into one. I guess this is not possible in earlier version of EE. This is all wonderful and reducing lot of code. But aren't there any serious implications with design of application. For example, I currently use EE 5 where presentation layer (JSF), business layer (EJB) and web service layer (JAX-RS) are clearly separated out. Three different classes and container manages the dependency injection. Is there any security hole in the "candy" version of combining all three in one like illustrated below.

```
/**
 * @author Arun Gupta
 */
@Named
@Stateless
@Path("movie")
public class MovieFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Movie> {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public MovieFacadeREST() {
        super(Movie.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(Movie entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void edit(Movie entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Movie find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Movie> getAll() {
        return super.getAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Movie> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is that tutorial? What you are asking should also be mentioned in that tutorial.

Comment: @Tiny: The code is linked above for its source

Answer (score 0):

[Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee6technologies-1955512.html) included [JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) 1.1, and errata C002 from the [JAX-RS 1.1 changelog](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr311/311changelog.1.1.html) required support for CDI (aka [JSR 299](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299)):

> In a product that also supports Managed Beans, implementations MUST
>   support use of Managed Beans as root resource classes, providers and
>   Application subclasses. In a product that also supports JSR 299,
>   implementations MUST similarly support use of JSR299-style managed
>   beans. Providers and Application subclasses MUST be singletons or use
>   application scope.

So, this kind of thing was previously possible.  See the [Worst ever Java EE 6 Blog](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ludo/archive/2009/05/worst_ever_java.html), which combined many EE 6 technologies into a single class.